# Question on partial derivatives of appropriate function with respect to another basis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, analytic-geometry, partial-derivative

Let the standard coordinate system of $\;\mathbb R^2\;\;,\;\{x,y\}\;$ and a rectangle $\;\mathcal R\;$. Take $\;x^* \;$ on the boundary of $\;\mathcal R\;$ and consider there the positive oriented orthonormal basis $\;\{τ,v\}\;$ where $\;v\;$ is the outward unit normal vector and $\;τ\;$ the tangent one.

> Is it true to claim that:
>
> $\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\;$ for
>   some non zero and non constant function $\;f\;$ and if yes,why?

It seems valid to me, although I'm missing the key in order to prove it. The change of coordinates and how this affects calculations, always confuses me a lot. Any help would be valuable!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if $f$ is the zero function?

Comment: Trivially true for any constant function.